# Browser errors were logged to the console , Error facing on shopify store

Tags: shopify

When we check page speed on Google the below is the error faced in Shopify store with Theme name is "Debut" , How to resolve this error ? Whether it is possible us to correct Shopify CDN ?

ReferenceError: Shopify is not defined at load (https://cdn.shopify.com/extensions/ffab615c-46c7-42aa-a3ba-2a56785868f0/inbox-205/assets/inbox-chat-loader.js:60:3) at https://cdn.shopify.com/extensions/ffab615c-46c7-42aa-a3ba-2a56785868f0/inbox-205/assets/inbox-chat-loader.js:87:3

https://cdn.shopify.com/extensions/ffab615c-46c7-42aa-a3ba-2a56785868f0/inbox-205/assets/inbox-chat-loader.js

I am exepcting the resolution of error which will improve the page speed of website.